# How to bind url in iframe src using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe

There is a method based on user id, getting the title and description, but video is not showing in IFRAME.

Aspx.cs code:

```
  public void getdata()
{

  bo.Para1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["userid"]) ? "no-img" : Request.QueryString["userid"];

 bl.videoDetais(bo, out  VDetails,out  Status);

 Lbl_title.Text = VDetails.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
 Txt_Description.Text = VDetails.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();  


  string url=null;

 url=VDetails.Rows[0]["YoutubeLink"].ToString();

 }
```

My Design IFRAME Code:

```
   <iframe width="480" height="360" src='<%# Eval("url") %>'
   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare iframe with some id as:

```
iframe id="myFrame" runat="server" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0></iframe>
```

in Page_Load set source attribute as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      string video_id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();  
      Label1.Text = video_id;
      string video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id;
myFrame.Attributes["src"] = video_url ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a url as a property, not a variable in your code behind and make sure you bind it.

```
public partial class Form1: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string url { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        getdata(); //your method which assigns a value to url
        DataBind();
    }
}
```